# Get caller variable name from constructor

Tags: php

I want to know the variable name that is calling an object.

For example:

```
ClassObj $var = new ClassObj();
```

Is it possible to get the variable name `$var` from the constructor within ClassObj?

Comment: No, it isn't and if you require such a functionality, you're doing something wrong. Maybe you should explain what you're doing and then someone might suggest a different approach.

Comment: Yes, it certainly was something wrong in the design. Solved by thinking a little bit more on the problem. Thanks!